# What's the best font for printing on a LED-printer?

Tags: fonts, printing, default

my impression is that text appears to be too thin, hence hard to read and appearing grey-ish, when using LaTeX. It may look reasonable when viewing a pdf, but it's worse than e.g. Word or any other textprocessor when printed.

Probably good solutions are already known: Which are they?

EXAMPLE 1, straight forward, KOMA-script:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}   % implicit font selection
\usepackage{blox}

\begin{document} ...
```

EXAMPLE 2, from some website, business letter:

```
\documentclass{g-brief2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % <<<
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lmodern}   % <<<
... % setting lot's of variables for the letters content
\begin{document}
    \begin{g-brief}
...
```

Scanned printouts:

- Word font is about double in "thickness"
- what's grey-ish on print is fuzzy here

[image]

Thanks for sharing your insights :)

P.S.: If that's relevant, my printer is a Samsung ML-3310D (but that shouldn't matter much, I suppose)

Comment: your two examples are badically the same, latin modern is essentially a technical re-implementation of the computer modern design (which is famously thin strokes) you could use a times clone eg `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` for a more robust font, or use lualatex and use exactly the fonts you are using in Word (lualatex can use system fonts)

Comment: Thanks // Right, that was my preliminary guess of how Latex works many times. // I'd like to avoid experiments with a few dozen printouts, and continue with one or a few proven fonts ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, just for my understanding: is it enoughto select Lualatex as output (e.g. from the Texmaker menu), or do I have to install it http://www.luatex.org/download.html ? // How do I specify a system font to use in lualatex?

Comment: luatex is part of texlive and miktex so you probably have it.  You can probably add `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Cambria}` to use the windows Cambria font for example. (search for fontspec on this site for thousands of examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED. According to @DavidCarlisle, this did the trick:

- use fontspec, set mainfont, taken from \Windows\font
- compile pdf via LuaLateX

Required code changes:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{fontspec}   % as proposed by @DavidCarlisle ...
\setmainfont{Calibri}   % ... include a Windows-font

\begin{document} ...
```

Thanks again :)

**P.S.**: It also seems to help to select "best printing" options with the printer.

Comment: glad you got it working:-)

Comment: Like The Beatles and Joe Cocker once sang: "i get by with a little help from my friends" ;-)

Comment: One can use the mlmodern (https://ctan.org/pkg/mlmodern?lang=en) and the newcm (https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern?lang=en) fonts if a thicker computer modern font is what is simply desired.

Comment: Maybe one should add that using Calibri for body text might not be everybody's first choice. A number of typographically knowledgable people say that longer parts of text should actually be printed in a serif font due to legibility. So, if the printer has a bad output that renders serif fonts illegible, it might be a good idea to invest in a better printing machine ... =)

Comment: Welcome to the world of Microsoft Word … Well, I converted to Latex, meanwhile …